# React useState - update all object values to true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have defined an object as follows in a file:

```
export const items = {
  first: false,
  second: false,
  third: false
}
```

I'm using it in a component as follows:

```
import { items } from 'file';
const [elements, setElements] = useState(items);
```

I have a method which gets called when a button is clicked - the method should change the all the values in `elements` to `true`

Using the following changes the values but it does not trigger a re-render of the component (which is what I need)

```
Object.keys(elements).forEach(element => elements[element] = true);
```

How can I use `setElements` to update all the values in `elements`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you are mutating the state object, which means that at the end, `prevState === nextState` and React bails out of rendering. An option is to use a new object and copy the props like this, using the same combo of `Object.keys` and `forEach` but adding an extra step:

```
setState(prevState => {
  const nextState = {}
  Object.keys(prevState).forEach(key => {
    nextState[key] = true
  })
  return nextState
})
```

Comment: I honestly assumed they did and just didn't include it in the sample :(

Comment: @pilchard when using the setter with Object.keys & forEach, I get the following:Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ first:boolean; second:boolean; third:boolean; }>'.

Comment: @murohima_1 the answer above is correct, you need to avoid mutating the current state and provide a new object reference for React to recognize a change. Your error looks like you are trying to simply pass the return of the `forEach` to the setter, but `forEach` [always returns undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value)

Comment: the answer above is using setState which I haven't mentioned in the question. I'm using useState

Comment: `setState` in this context is just a generic stand-in for your named setter, so `setElements(prevState ...);`

Comment: Getting the following when using the solution above: Argument of type '(elements: { first:boolean; second:boolean; third:boolean; }) => {}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ first: boolean; second: boolean; third: boolean; }>'.
  Type '(elements: { first: boolean; second: boolean; third: boolean; }) => {}' is not assignable to type '(prevState: { first: boolean; second: boolean; third: boolean; }) => { ...; }'.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '{ first: boolean; second: boolean; third: boolean; }': first, second, third.

Comment: This is a subtle typescript error which is a different question. I would recommend not using typescript until you understand the underlying javascript.

Comment: So, there's no workaround for this issue in typescript?

Comment: If you have a static list of properties, why not just do it as `setElements({ first: true, second: true, third: true })`? I thought you had dynamic keys all around ;)